# Jira Jenkins Integration | Issue Id

Tags: jenkins, jira, jira-plugin

I was trying to get an SVN, Jenkins and Jira integration going. The aim being to change the status of a ticket/issue to 'Fixed' when it is referred to in an SCM comment. The process being orchestrated by Jenkins. The flow details are

- developer puts in the Jira ticket number (MDP-1) on an SVN commit
  message.
- The build is kicked off in JenkinsJenkins (using the Jira
  plugin) can figure out the Jira ticket referred to it in the SVN
  commit message. It updates the Jira ticket by putting in a Jira
  comment.
- So far, this is working great!
- Now, I also want to change
  the status of the ticket to 'fixed'. I am trying to use the Jenkins
  step (Progress jenkins issues by workflow action). I am unable to
  access the Jira issue ID/ticket number.

I know, under the hood, the Jira plugin has access to this. Thats why it is able to put in a comment to the Jira ticket in the first case. Question is how/what variable do I use to get access to this Jira ticket# in Jenkins

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I actually got this working with another Jenkins plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jira-Ext+Plugin).

This captures the Jira issue_id(s) captured in the SCM commit message and exposes them in an environment variable.

Just what I was looking for!

[image]